# Hide a table row element inside a table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to hide a table row when a td has no value, but my javascript function is failing. It keeps going on the "else".

HTML

```
<table>
   <tr id="locOfWorkRow"> 
     <td><span>Location of Work</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><span>This is the label</span></td>
     <td id="road"><span></span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
var r = document.getElementById('road').innerHTML; 

 if(r == ""){ alert("on if");
   document.getElementById('locOfWorkRow').style.display = "none";
 }else{
    alert("on else");
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking for an empty string, check whether the length of the `innerHTML` is more than 0 instead.

```
r.length > 0
```

If the string is empty, the length will return 0, if the the innerHTML contains any characters the length will return a value greater than 0.

What you are currently doing with `r == ""` is checking whether r is empty and that is why the "on if" alert is showing.

See this example

http://jsfiddle.net/9ny6598u/

Comment: Apology but I put a wrong statement at first. The row should be hidden if td has NO value on it.

Comment: So if the td is empty you want to hide it? See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9ny6598u/3/ . Please update your question to reflect that this is what you actually require. The td <td id="road"></td> is now emptied and locOfWorkRow is now hidden in the if(r.length == 0). let me know if thats not what you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
var r = document.getElementById('road').innerHTML;

if (r.length > 0) {
    alert("on if");
    document.getElementById('locOfWorkRow').style.display = "none";
} else {
    alert("on else");
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3jy3zsca/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong if condition

use if(r != "") instead of r==""

Answer (score 0):

> Actually your if condition is wrong

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/bvop1gdq/

```
if(r !== ""){ alert("on if");
   document.getElementById('locOfWorkRow').style.display = "none";
 }else{
    alert("on else");
 }
```

Or

```
if (r.length > 0) {
    alert("on if");
    document.getElementById('locOfWorkRow').style.display = "none";
} else {
    alert("on else");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are not loading your javascript before page try to write your javascript at the end of the page so the element is available and you not get the null reference.

and by innerhtml you got the "span Road 1 /span" so write condition as per that. and its work fine if you load your script below body.

Make sure you have loaded your script after html load.

Answer (score 0):

using undefined as comparison instead of empty string and also use === instead of ==

```
if(r === undefined){ alert("on if");
  document.getElementById('locOfWorkRow').style.display = "none";
}else{
  alert("on else");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of innerHTML you may use innerText or textContent

```
var r = document.getElementById('road').innerText || document.getElementById('road').textContent;
```